# CKEditor 4 Manually Invoking Numbered List

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Given I have disabled toolbar and created my own toolbar with my own markup (with affix-like functionality).

I need to recreate functionality of numbered list and bulleted list buttons of ckeditor toolbar when I click on corresponding buttons of my toolbar.

None of

```
editor.execCommand('numberedlist')
editor.execCommand('numberedListStyle')
editor.execCommand('bulletedlist')
editor.execCommand('bulletedListStyle')
```

works.

Maybe I mess with parameters and I need to pass more parameters.

What command I need to call on ckeditor to create ordered and unordered list from current selection?

**UPD**

When I select some text in ckeditor, open up my web inspector and enter in console:

```
> content_editors.ru.execCommand('bold')
  true
```

It works like a charm, text become bold, but no luck with `numberedlist` or `bulletedlist`:

```
> content_editors.ru.execCommand('numberedlist')
  false
> content_editors.ru.execCommand('bulletedlist')
  false
```

Lists were working until I disabled toolbar plugin in `config.js`:

```
config.removePlugins = 'toolbar'
config.allowedContent = 'p h3 h4 h5 h6 strong em u; a[!href]; img[!src]'
```

**UPD2**

So diving in what I done for the sake of disabling toolbar.. I haven't allowed `ul and ol` tags!

So simple

```
// config.allowedContent = 'p h3 h4 h5 h6 strong em u; a[!href]; img[!src]'
config.allowedContent = 'p h3 h4 h5 h6 strong em u; a[!href]; img[!src]; ul ol;'
```

did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call:

```
editor.execCommand( 'numberedlist' );
editor.execCommand( 'bulletedlist' );
```

ofc `editor` must be a valid ckeditor instance object. You can fetch instance from `CKEDITOR.instances`.

I.e. for [http://ckeditor.com/demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo%20CKEditor%20official%20demo) you have to execute following call:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.execCommand( 'numberedlist' );
```

Comment: It just returns ```false``` and nothing happens to selected text. I have valid ckeditor instance, because I can successfully execute commands like ```bold, link, etc```. But not ```numberedlist and bulletedlist```.

Comment: Marek, thank you for pushing me to investigate further, why code that should work just returns ```false```. Your answer is right. This is working, if ```ul and ol``` is allowed.